# Create a span element inside another element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-calendar-api

This code is from google calender.

```
var dateString =  (startJSDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + startJSDate.getDate();
  if (!startDateTime.isDateOnly()) {
  dateString += " @ " + startJSDate.getHours() + ":" + 
  padNumber(startJSDate.getMinutes());
}
 dateString = "<span>" +dateString + "</span>";
 var li = document.createElement('li');
```

I need to add a span tag around the variable dateString, adding them as above returns "1234" as text on the page.

The string is rendered as such:

```
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' - ' + dateString));
```

Comment: did you try `li.innerHTML = dateString ` ?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try following code, create span using createElement and insert date string in it as innerHTML. Then append span to li.

```
var dateSpan = document.createElement('span')
dateSpan.innerHTML = dateString;
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.appendChild(dateSpan);
```

Comment: Never seen such a coincidence, copied the code inside my project and even names of the variables matched... 

Comment: @Chaki_Black: that's called developer's language :P

Comment: Worked like wonders, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if you can use jquery, then the method .wrap() will do it what you want.